# iOS Notes and foreign WIFI hotspot security

Tags: wifi, notes.app

If I connect with my iPhone to a foreign wifi hotspot are my Notes in danger? Does it automatically transfer Notes on new connection? If I didn't open the Notes app, or even if I did open it, can a Wifi hotspot read it?

Comment: Foreign as in a WiFi hotspot in a country other than the one you live in, or a WiFi Hotspot not under your personal control?

Answer (score 4):

No, iPhone does not broadcast your entire phone contents in the clear.

Any iCloud data sent over the network is protected by HTTPS.

Not that it matters because of the previous statement, but if an iCloud sync happened to transfer some data at the time, this transfer would only be a delta updates; content which one party does not have, not the entire contents of iPhone notes.

Comment: Ok thanks, any other potential risk when connecting to foreign wifi? If i omit the scenario of some app using the http clear text.

Comment: There's likely many potential risks, however the most common hacks are: 1) Re-routing you to fake versions of websites and capturing your login info. For example you try to go to your bank on the wifi and it reroutes you to a similar looking page, then captures your login credentials. 2) Any non encrypted access may be intercepted, such as email accounts that are not using SSL. Search for "Man in the middle" hacks and you can read up on all sorts of things people try to do when they manage the wifi network you're joining. I'd recommend considering a VPN service like privateinternetaccess.com